# How to get only unique values of a 2d array

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to get the following 2d array from:

[[Option 10, 2.0], [Option 10, 2.0], [Option 9, 1.0], [Option 7, 1.0]]

to

[[Option 10, 2.0], [Option 9, 1.0], [Option 7, 1.0]]

I found this post ([Splitting a 2D array using some() , by date, avoiding duplicates. Just want 1 unique email, not row. Where am i wrong here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21617453/splitting-a-2d-array-using-some-by-date-avoiding-duplicates-just-want-1-un)) that has a very efficient way of getting unique values, but I cannot figure out how to apply it to my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use case is simpler than the one you refer to.

try this for example :

```
function myFunction() {
  var source = [['Option 10', 2], ['Option 10', 2], ['Option 9', 1], ['Option 7', 1]];
  var dest = [];
  dest.push(source[0]);
  for(var n = 1 ; n< source.length ; n++){
    if(dest.join().indexOf(source[n].join()) == -1){dest.push(source[n])};
  }
  Logger.log(dest);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because 'unique' is not always simple to describe, I often use a pattern which is is, in effect, a variation of Serge's correct answer using ES5 array map/filter functions.

*An edited version:*

```
function hash(arr) {

  // in this case the hash method is the same as Serge's Array.join() method,
     but could be customised to suit whatever condition you need to generate
     bespoke comparators such as where `1 + 3` should match `2 + 2`, or where
     particular columns in the array can be omitted

  return arr.join();
}

function myFunction() {
  var source = [['Option 10', 2], ['Option 10', 2], ['Option 9', 1], ['Option 7', 1]];
  var hash = source.map(
    function (row) {
      return hash(row);
    }
  );

  source = source.filter(
    function (filterRow, i) {
      return hash.slice(0, i).indexOf(hash(filterRow)) < 0;
    }
  );

  Logger.log(source);
}
```

I only include this as there are times when your comparison may need to flex a little. In your example this isn't important which is why Serge's is correct, but I share to show a potential expansion food for thought for when unique needs to be '*tweaked*'